# How to know which Image the MouseClick event occured?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, mouseevent

I have 2 images for 2 players on my windows form.  I have added a `MouseClick` event for both of  them. Now when I mouse click, it activates both the events for both the players. I wanted to know only one player where I am clicking. 
How do I do that?

```
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this._player1_MouseClick);
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this._player2_MouseClick);
```

Comment: You are clicking only one thing (whatever `this` means in your code) - you are not clicking different images

Comment: Sender will contain the object that had the click unless its called programatically

Comment: Ok. I thought so. So for me if I want my code to know the exact image I want, do I need to play with coordinates? is there any other way?

Comment: You're registering the mouse click event to your form instead of the players. E.g: `pl1.MouseClick += ...`, where `pl1` can be, for instance, a `PictureBox`. I would also suggest you to use `UserControl`s.

Comment: Thank you.. My player has an Image which I am instantiating dynamically.  Looks like I have to use PictureBox instead. I do not see MouseClick event for my Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have two `PictureBox` controls with images. Thus you have posted code from designer, I also assume that you are subscribing to events via designer.

1. Select one of `PictureBox` controls
2. In *Events* tab find `Click` property, type-in `Player_Click` as handler name and hit Enter. You have subscribed to `Click` event of first control.
3. Select second `PictureBox`
4. In *Events* tab find `Click` property, click on drop-down and select `Player_Click` as well. Hit Enter. You have used same event handler to subscribe to `Click` event of second control.
5. Now go to code view (you can double click any of those controls for that) and find `Player_Click` method

In order to find which control was clicked you need to cast `sender` argument to `PictureBox` type:

```
private void Player_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;
    // use control which was clicked. e.g. get it's name
    var name = pictureBox.Name; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But what if I am instantiating players dynamically?

Comment: @TruptiPanditSamant then use `player.Click += Player_Click` for each player which you are instantiating